# React Native on android, images not being bundled when uploaded to play store

Tags: react-native

I am using `v57.4`, when I install my app no images are included.

I have tried to run:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/a
pp/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

This doesn't work as there is no `index.android.bundle`

How can I bundle my images?